# Input to method as strings

Tags: scala

Consider a string

```
val inp = "name,age,city"
```

Consider my method with input types

```
def partitions(colName:String,colNames:Sting*) : String
```

I have to call method as partitions("name","age","city") using comma separated list of strings in my variable inp.

Comment: `inp.split(",").toSeq :_*`

Comment: Are you kidding me? `partitions("someName", inp.split(",").toSeq :_*)`

Answer (score 0):

```
val inp = "name,age,city"
def partitions(colName:String,colNames:String*) : String
val inpSeq=  inp.split(",").toSeq
partitions(inpSeq.head,inpSeq.tail)
```